# Solar cells, current limited by smallest cell?

Tags: current, solar-cell

I've read on a bunch of different sites that:

"You also do not want to mix different sized cells together because the current or AMPS of your solar panel will be limited by the smallest cell in the group"

"the output capacity of the entire panel is limited to the output of the smallest cell on the panel"

"the current will be limited by the smallest cell in the group and the larger cells will not work to their full potential."

"mixing cell sizes is not a good idea. This is because the current your panel can produce will be limited by the smallest cell in the group and the larger cells won't work to their full potential"

... and I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because a solar cell acts as a constant current source, and you normally connect a few of them in series to get an usable voltage. See also these answers/comments: [How does the maximum current of solar cells combine in series?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/67460/35660)